# Group by and exclude minimum and maximum from results

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

I have data similar to the following:

```
Date        ID          Amount
10-Jun-14   978500302   163005350
17-Jun-14   978500302   159947117
24-Jun-14   978500302   159142342
1-Jul-14    978500302   159623201
8-Jul-14    978500302   143066033
14-Jul-14   978500302   145852027
15-Jul-14   978500302   148595751
```

Is there a way in oracle that I can get an average of this data, which excludes the highest and lowest value? I can get the overall average by doing a `GROUP BY ID`, and then `AVG(Amount)`. But how can I do this while excluding min and max?

Comment: (SUM(Amount)-Min(Amount)-Max(Amount))/(COUNT(Amount)-2)

Comment: Are you talking about the average for the whole table or for each ID?

Comment: What would happen if you are max/min is repeated? What would be average if all the Amounts are same?

Comment: Good question - it would be a very rare case. If it were the case, then it wouldn't matter which of the duplicate values were dropped. Exactly one min and one max need to be dropped, no matter what.

Comment: What is your requirement? If you want to simply have a "robust" characteristics of your data set, you might want to use the median or use a filter for outliers which is a bit smarter than using only all mins/maxes. For example ignore all values < 1st and 99th percentile or 1.5 times stddev.

Comment: @eckes - Good suggestions, that might be something that I look at in the future. The purpose of the query is to be a test for heading in that direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to use analytic functions to get the minimum and maximum values before aggregating:

```
select id, avg(amount)
from (select d.*,
             min(amount) over (partition by id) as mina,
             max(amount) over (partition by id) as maxa
      from data d
     ) d
where amount > mina and amount < maxa
group by id;
```

Comment: This is probably the right way to do it - I feel like this sort of thing could be slow, though. The nested select has to query through the entire table again, doesn't it? It happens that my data above is actually generated through a nested select, so doing this would require running that same select again (right?).

Comment: @EvanDefend . . . Oracle has quite a good query optimizers.  You would need to look at the execution plan to see how the query is really being executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, avg(amount)
  from tbl t
 where id not in (select id from tbl group by id having count(distinct amount) > 2)
    or (amount <> (select min(x.amount) from tbl x where x.id = t.id)
   and amount <> (select max(x.amount) from tbl x where x.id = t.id))
 group by id
```

The first line in the WHERE clause is there to retain IDs that do not have more than 2 values. They would otherwise be excluded from the results.

If you would rather they be excluded, you can get rid of that line.

You could also try the following:

```
select id, avg(amount)
  from (select id, amount
          from tbl
        minus
        select id, min(amount)
          from tbl
         group by id
        minus
        select id, max(amount)
          from tbl
         group by id)
 group by id
```

Comment: Ouch.  The first query is likely to RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) each individual group (the `MIN(...)`/`MAX(...)` subqueries have to be run _for every row_).  And even though `MINUS` is a set operation, it's usually not as optimized as `UNION (ALL)` or even joins.  Doing these queries as (anti-)joins likely yields better/more performant results (although I would be interested in `EXPLAIN` plans that say otherwise, for data at scale).

Comment: Figured I would just throw everything out there, I imagine that the 2nd query would perform better than the first. However the first would retain IDs that might otherwise be excluded, not sure if that's important or not to the OP

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
SELECT ID, 
(SUM(Amount)-Min(Amount)-Max(Amount))/(COUNT(Amount)-2) AS AVG
FROM yourTbl
Group By ID
```

As pointed out by @Clockwork-Muse this will work only when the row count is more than 2.

Comment: Hmm... that seems alright. It works for AVG() - but it would be much more difficult to do it if I needed some other metric, like STDDEV. I'll probably end up using it, for simplicity - many thanks.

Comment: If the minimum or maximum amount is repeated more than once they would inappropriately contribute to the average.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia Per OP exactly only 1 max and 1 min value needs to be dropped.

Comment: @OneZeroPundit where does he say that? if that is what he is intending then I agree it's fine, but he just says "excludes the highest and lowest value". It is unclear what he wants to happen if the highest value occurs 2, 3, 4+ times for the same ID.

Comment: @OneZeroPundit I just read the comments, doesn't look like he cares one way or the other.

Comment: Side note, this isn't safe for groups that have 2 or fewer rows (divide by zero error).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Nice catch. How did I miss it. It will depend on what OP wants in such a case.

Comment: @EvanDefend What would be the average if rowcount is 2 or less.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment saying "Exactly one min and one max need to be dropped, no matter what", a variation of Gordon's approach would always exclude one row only if the min or max amount was duplicated:

```
select id, avg(amount)
from (
  select id, amount,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by amount) as min_rn,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by amount desc) as max_rn
  from t42
)
where min_rn > 1
and max_rn > 1
group by id;
```

This would behave the same as Gordon's if you used `rank()` or `dense_rank()` rather than `row_number()` as they allow duplicate results. Any of these will only hit the real table once.

To see how the ranking works, with your min and max amounts repeated for effect:

```
select dt, id, amount,
  row_number() over (partition by id order by amount) as min_rn,
  row_number() over (partition by id order by amount desc) as max_rn,
  rank() over (partition by id order by amount) as min_rnk,
  rank() over (partition by id order by amount desc) as max_rnk
from t42;

DT                ID     AMOUNT     MIN_RN     MAX_RN    MIN_RNK    MAX_RNK
--------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
23-JUL-14  978500302  143066033          1          8          1          8 
08-JUL-14  978500302  143066033          2          9          1          8 
14-JUL-14  978500302  145852027          3          7          3          7 
15-JUL-14  978500302  148595751          4          6          4          6 
24-JUN-14  978500302  159142342          5          5          5          5 
01-JUL-14  978500302  159623201          6          4          6          4 
17-JUN-14  978500302  159947117          7          3          7          3 
24-JUL-14  978500302  163005350          8          2          8          1 
10-JUN-14  978500302  163005350          9          1          8          1
```

With the same data, using `row_number() gives:

```
        ID AVG(AMOUNT)
---------- -----------
 978500302   154175974
```

Using `rank()` gives:

```
        ID AVG(AMOUNT)
---------- -----------
 978500302   154632088
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d54c9/1).

You will get no result for an ID with only 1 or 2 amounts, which may be what you want to happen, and might make sense for consistency. If you did want to allow for that possibility though and include the min and max when those are the only values, you could also count how many raw rows there are for each ID and include the min and max if there aren't enough:

```
select id, avg(amount)
from (
  select id, amount,
    count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by amount) as min_rn,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by amount desc) as max_rn
  from t42
)
where (cnt < 3 or min_rn > 1)
and (cnt < 3 or max_rn > 1)
group by id;
```